# Same number in hex and decimal returns different id

Tags: python, python-3.x

I presumed `id()` of immutable data types in python should be the same if the same value be used

But this fails if i store decimal and hex version of same integer :

```
In [1]: a = 0x1234                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [2]: b = 4660                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: a == b                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[3]: True

In [4]: id(a) == id(b)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[4]: False

In [5]: id(a)                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[5]: 140579138155600

In [6]: id(b)                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: 140579138154736
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about conversion, Python interpreter creates object every time you assign a big integer so those have different objects. numbers between -1 to 255 are created when interpreter starts and they have same `id` in all program.